# Need a help for paypal reccuring payments

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am new in paypal.My site contains a plan select page.If we select a plan and pay through paypal ,it working perfectly.But i want another option "renew plan automatically".But i don't have any idea about it.Is it possible to pay amount with out credit card  details? My page only contains amount,return,item_name,business and notify_url and if we click paypal button it redirected to paypal site. How can I create a Recurring Payments Profile? I found some code but it contains credit card details.

```
$methodToCall = 'CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile';
                $nvpRecurring ='&BILLINGPERIOD='.$billingPeriod.'&BILLINGFREQUENCY='.$billingFreq.'&PROFILESTARTDATE='.$profileStartDate.'&INITAMT='.$initAmt.'&FAILEDINITAMTACTION='.$failedInitAmtAction.'&DESC='.$desc.'&AUTOBILLAMT='.$autoBillAmt.'&PROFILEREFERENCE='.$profileReference;


            $nvpstr='&PAYMENTACTION='.$paymentAction.'&AMT='.$amount.'&CREDITCARDTYPE='.$creditCardType.'&ACCT='.$creditCardNumber.'&EXPDATE='.         $padDateMonth.$expDateYear.'&CVV2='.$cvv2Number.'&FIRSTNAME='.$firstName.'&LASTNAME='.$lastName.'&STREET='.$address1.'&CITY='.$city.'&STATE='.$state.'&ZIP='.$zip.'&COUNTRYCODE=US&CURRENCYCODE='.$currencyCode.$nvpRecurring;
```

But I don't have any credit card details.Any one please help me...

Comment: please help me.. Without any effort how to help you...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a documentation [recurring-payments-basics](http://payum.org/doc/0.9/PaypalExpressCheckoutNvp/recurring-payments-basics) on how one can setup and use paypal recurring payments using payum. Examples are written in pure php so any special frameworks knowledge are not required. If you are not familiar with payum I'd suggest start from [get-it-started](http://payum.org/doc/0.9/Core/get-it-started) and after read the recurring payments documentation.

P.S. You can also look at working examples in the [payum sandbox](http://sandbox.payum.forma-dev.com/) written on symfony2 framework ([source code](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundleSandbox)).

Comment: Link  recurring-payments-basics is broken now. At the moment this one is working:  [recurring-payments-basics](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/src/Payum/Paypal/ExpressCheckout/Nvp/Resources/docs/recurring-payments-basics.md)

Answer (score 0):

If you to stick with a basic button (Payments Standard) you can setup a Subscription button instead of a Buy Now button.  This would allow people to setup a profile that gets automatically paid every week, month, quarter, year, or however you set it up.

If you want to use the actual Recurring Payments API you'll need to make API calls with a programming language.  If you're using PHP I'd recommend taking a look at my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/).  It would make the API integration very simple for you.